# Windows Phone Emulator is unable to set the VHD on the virtual machine

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, hyper-v, vhd

[image: I've got this error when tried to build the project]

I'm using `Windows 10`
and `Hyper-V` virtual machine!!!

How can I fix this error? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried searching for the last line in that message? Suspect you'll find a bunch of results to look into

Comment: Oop.. I've tried searching the title for many times, but the last line, I have not. Let me try.. :)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yeah.. I restarted the Hyper-V and It worked :) Thank you